# Upstart script not executing pre-start script when the process is respawned

Tags: bash, centos6, upstart

I'm trying to get Upstart sending me e-mails when a process is respawned.
So, following upstart stanzas, here's my upstart script for ntpd service (just as an example):

```
/etc/init/ntpd.conf

### ntpd

script

mail -s "ntpd Service Respawned" my_email@gmail.com
control + D

end script

respawn

exec /etc/init.d/ntpd start
```

Then, I reload the process (`initctl reload ntpd`) in order to get upstart to reload ntpd.conf's config. Then `kill -9` the process to force its respawn.
Here's `/var/log/message.log`:

```
init: ntpd main process (12446) killed by KILL signal
init: ntpd main process ended, respawning
```

And the e-mail is never sent.  I've tried with post-start and exec but it doesn't work either.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "ntpd Service Respawned" | mail -s "ntpd Service Respawned" my_email@gmail.com
```

Try with this.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this one.

What I did was add the following in my Upstart script:

```
respawn

pre-start script

mail -s "ntpd Service Respawned" my_address@gmail.com
control + D

end script

exec /etc/init.d/ntpd start
```

That works like a charm.
I think Upstart does pay much attention to the statements order.

Thanks!!!

Comment: For the future readers, the issue may have been that to OP used both `script` and `exec` in the same upstart script. This is not allowed. The fix (I believe) was to use `pre-start` rather than `script`. Order does not matter in the large part.